# Recommendation for method to archive email

Tags: email, imap, archive

I use Apple's Mail application. I have IMAP email through an ISP, which comes with a limited amount of server space, which I am near filling (before greater payments are required).

I therefore have several thousand email messages which are still 'synced' to the IMAP server. I want to 'archive' some proportion (let's say, all emails prior to a certain date) by storing them locally on my Mac and removing them from the IMAP server.

What's the best way to achieve this? Particularly in an automated way?

Using Rules is the obvious candidate, though I have to set criteria for both Date Sent and Date Received, and only in number of days. It could be possible to set up a Smart Mailbox based on age, and then apply some action to the contents.

For extra points: I have two Macs, whose emails are currently in sync via the IMAP server. How can I archive email to local folders on both Macs? I'm suspecting having to turn off internet connection before archiving on each one, then re-connecting.

Any thoughts on the best way to achieve this would be welcome. Macs are on Mojave and Catalina.

Comment: Can you connect to your account with POP? That would download from your mail server to your local machine. I do that with Gmail on one of my Macs. Mail.app is set up to connect to my Gmail accounts via POP (with leave a copy on the server checked) and then I can delete email via the web interface on other systems and stuff I want to keep is downloaded to the "master" account leaving me with a local archive. It is a little extra work but for the amount of email I get has been working for me since Gmail was in public beta.

Comment: Doesn't that mean that if I want to delete one email, I'd have to delete the local copy on each Mac (and iPhone) and then delete it off the POP server?

Comment: Depends on how you set it up. I chose to set up POP on **ONE** Mac and leave on server. you could set up POP, download *everything,* move that email to local only mailboxes and then turn IMAP back on. You would have ALL email on one Mac, cleared out your server quota and go back to managing as IMAP. There are a lot of different ways to do this. If this sounds like it is moving in the right direction for you it is a matter of figuring out what steps will get you a result you can live with.

Comment: Other possibilities are just archiving email on one Mac, and then exporting the Archived Mailbox and importing it on the other Mac. But really, I'd like this to be automated, rather than a seasonal harvest.

Comment: Can‘t you just manually copy old mails into a local mail folder on both Macs and then delete them from the Mail Server?